# How do I access the global variable?

Tags: python

```
global a # Let global variable be a
a = None

def test():
   a = 2 #Assigned the value 2
   print(a) #The result of this is 2 (Which I desire)

def test2:
  print(a) #The result is None (But I expect it to be 2)
# Please Help me with this
```

Comment: Put the global statement in `test`.

Comment: You need to put "global a" on the row over a = 2

Comment: I want global variable outside function only. Thanks for suggestions

Comment: If you want your program to work, you need to put statements in the places that the language requires them. Putting a global statement at the top of your program is pointless.